# Minikube cannot access Podman Registry

Tags: minikube, podman, apple-silicon

I am trying to run java microservices on an Macbook Pro with M1 Arm processor.

The Internet is awash with instructions on this.  Most of them declare victory at getting Minikube to run.  I haven't found any that carry this all the way to having even a Hello World service deployed all the way from source code.

My current toolset is Podman with Minikube using Containerd.  I'm not unwaveringly committed to this setup although it does seem the most desirable to me, and I'd like to get it working because I foolishly believe this is the last hurdle.

I have made it this far:

Created Podman VM with generous allocations of cpu, memory, etc
Modified registries.conf

```
unqualified-search-registries = ["docker.io"]
registries = ['localhost:41597']
```

Installed Minikube and start with --driver=podman --container-runtime-containerd

Minikube addons: storage-provisioner, ingress-dns, dashboard, registry-creds, logviewer, metallb, default-storageclass, metrics-server, ingress, registry

Told minikube to use docker registry: minikube -p minikube docker-env

Then I can build an image using podman build and it shows up in the podman image repository

But when I try to install it with helm I see this error in the Pod Events:

> failed to resolve reference "localhost:41597/auth-server:latest"

Poking at podman with postman I get an http 200 for localhost:41597/v2 so that endpoint is good.  I am of course less certain about what "localhost" means inside kubernetes, but for right now I'm hoping for the best.

The problem is that auth-server is not valid (404).  Even though the image is clearly there:

```
REPOSITORY                   TAG          IMAGE ID      CREATED        SIZE
localhost/auth-server        latest       69b8f90684e2  16 hours ago   391 MB
```

Any advice on my apparent registry problem - or links to a better solution greatly appreciated!